Settings "When you flip this switch" language problem
There is a "Settings" page available in your profile page. Some of the setting descriptions start with "When you flip this switch". Maybe "flip" means "enable" in some US English dialects, but normally it means toggle, as in change the state. Could it say "When you enable this switch" instead, so that it is unambiguous?
Also, a simple checkbox would be a better visual indicator than a slide switch and it would avoid the need for any "When enabled", or similar, text. The Q&A Checkbox vs toggle on User Experience Stack Exchange agrees with me on the former.

"Enable a switch" sounds very odd to me, as if you're encouraging it to do something bad. Since the text refers to a change of state, I'm not sure I follow your argument - can you clarify?

@W.O. Yes, I think just "enable this" would be better

Its an on off toggle that 1) is skeumorphic 2) looks like a switch 3) has colours. Switch seems appropriate to my eyes

This phrasing is not used at all on the Edit Email Settings Page and there are a lot of similar toggle widgets there too.

@JourneymanGeek I totally agree however I think their point is more about the "flip" part, which is ambiguous (On? Off? It doesn't matter, all that matters is for it to be flipped? - I'm having a hard time thinking poeple would understand it this way, but since we're arguing semantics - that's exactly what the phrase technically means)

+1 for the second suggestion. From a user experience perspective, I hate these kind of slide switches. I never know which side is on as they are not marked, and it took me a long time to figure out I shouldn't worry too much about how to flip them, but it's done in a counterintuitive way that completely breaks their supposed "skeumorphism", to borrow Journeyman Geek's term (you don't flip a real-world switch by sticking your finger between the end-positions of the switch). Ordinary checkboxes are so much better.

The original is confusing more so than strictly incorrect (since you have to remember the default is off, or assume that it's referring to when it's flipped on).  The best option is probably "When enabled" (short, unambiguous, and no UX metaphors) which is already the wording for one setting.

Agreed. Enabled/disabled is clear.

I just added to the question to mention that a simple checkbox would be better than a slide switch, in my opinion and that of many others.
